# Send cv2 video stream for face recognition

Tags: python, numpy, sockets, struct, pickle

I'm struggling with a problem to send a cv2 videostream (webcam) to a server (which shall be used later for face recognition).

I keep getting the following error for the server:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 67, in <module>
    small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src data type = 18 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

The server looks like this:

```
if client_socket:
  
    while True:
        packet = client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
        frame = np.array(packet)
        small_frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
        rgb_small_frame = small_frame[:, :, ::-1]
```

And here's the client:

```
while True:
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while vid.isOpened():
        time.sleep(0.5)
        img, frame = vid.read()
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, 4 * 1024)
        a = pickle.dumps(frame)
        message = struct.pack("Q", len(a)) + a
        try:
            client_socket.sendall(message)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise Exception(e)
```

Anyone any idea?

As it's a data stream of bytes, I tried to include for instance the sleep function to allow for more processing. Also tried to isolate the client's picture but also got errors.

Comment: Did you try to encode and decode your image https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74724858/issue-with-struct-unpack-typeerror-tuple-object-cannot-be-interpreted-as-a

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code. Regarding your question: You are passing a byte string to `resize`:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cv2.resize(np.array(b"Hello"), (0, 0), fx=0.25, fy=0.25)
```

Output:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'resize'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - src data type = 18 is not supported
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Please consider:

- don't use pickle for this kind of task, but compress the data to png or similar before sending it
- pass the data length before sending the data and use it on server side to collect the complete data before uncompressing it

Comment: Thanks for your tips, will work on it!